# Requirement to create a custom SharePoint Timer Job within a single solution

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list

I have created the SharePoint Timer Job with the reference of this site http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S.

Using the single WSP can I create multiple features within the single soution with different intervals of scheduling?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply repeat those instructions from Step 2 on. You could create dozens of unique timer jobs and deploy them in a single WSP.

Comment: I tried this senario also. I have created two different feature and classes within the single solution. I can able to activate both features but I am not able to run the second job.